# Airflow python callable function reusable

Tags: python, airflow

*airflow_version = 1.10.2; python_version = 3.6.8*

I am having trouble understanding how to make a python callable more reusable to airflow's PythonOperator, as the same function declared within the dag file itself works, but importing it from an helper lib fails.

So, the following **works**:

```
def my_function(temp_file, task_id, **kwargs):

    xcom_vals = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=task_id)

    if not xcom_vals:
        return 'Xcom message not retrieved'

    ack_messages = []

    for item in xcom_vals:

        ack_messages += <do stuff>

    return ack_messages

with DAG(<dag args>):

    process_messages = PythonOperator(
        task_id='get_messages',
        python_callable=my_function,
        op_kwargs={'task_id': 'previous_task_id',
                    'temp_file': temp_file},
        provide_context=True,
    )
```

But, moving *my_function* to a module lib/helpers.py and then importing it fails with error.

```
Broken DAG: [path to dag] cannot import my_function
```

**NOTE**: lib/helpers.py contains other functions (although more simple) that are successfully imported and used in the current and other DAG's.

How should *my_function* be implemented so that it is callable by other dags?

Comment: I had a similar problem what solved it for me was update the plugin path in file airflow.cfg plugins_folder = /airflow/plugins

Comment: Actually plugins_folder is already set to $airflow_home/plugins. You are saying that my_function should be implemented with its own custom operator?

Comment: @dorvak libs is subpath to dags, so folder structure is `airflow -- dags -- libs`, and libs is a py module so, __init__.py is there :\

Comment: @dorvak libs has a `__init__.py`, on my previous comment double underscore was parsed as md. Thing is libs/helper.py contains other functions (although more simple) that are successfully imported and used in the current and other DAG's!

Comment: Alright, sorry, for the confusion (deleted my comments)

Comment: I tried to reproduce you example in a docker-container using the same Airflow and Python versions and can't see any error. Can you post your import-statement?

Comment: Thanks! Here it is `from lib.helpers import post_success_slack, my_function` (post_success_slack works fine, as well as other imported functions :\ )

Comment: @MiguelSerrano Please sort out your s's. In the question you write that you are importing from lib__s__/helpe__r__.py, but the import statement in the comment says li__b__.helper__s__

Comment: Good catch @SergiyKolesnikov

Comment: If it is not a typo in the code/module names, then I do not see any reason for it not working... An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this one out, it came down to the airflow UI and scheduler not parsing the libs folders correctly, some kind of lag behaviour after a git sync? So both the UI and scheduler were parsing the dag file correctly, but not the lib folder.

What solved this behaviour in the end was a restart both to the UI and scheduler pod (we're running airflow on kubernetes) and that was it.